# Bland-Altman plot with confidence interval boundary in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot **Bland-Altman** graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def bland_altman_plot(data1, data2, *args, **kwargs):
    data1     = np.asarray(data1)
    data2     = np.asarray(data2)
    mean      = np.mean([data1, data2], axis=0)
    diff      = data1 - data2                   # Difference between data1 and data2
    md        = np.mean(diff)                   # Mean of the difference
    sd        = np.std(diff, axis=0)            # Standard deviation of the difference

    plt.scatter(mean, diff, *args, **kwargs)
    plt.axhline(md,           color='gray', linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(md + 1.96*sd, color='gray', linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(md - 1.96*sd, color='gray', linestyle='--')

from numpy.random import random

bland_altman_plot(random(10), random(10))
plt.title('Bland-Altman Plot')
plt.show()
```

The above code produces the following result:
[image: Bland-Altman Plot]

I am trying to plot a confidence interval boundary as well like the following plot. Let say the confidence interval coordinates for the top line are:

> Left (0.3, 0.5), (0.3, 0.4) and Right (0.9, 0.5), (0.9, 0,4)

For bottom line are:

> Left (0.3, 0.7), (0.3, 0.5) and Right (0.9, 0.7), (0.9, 0.5)

[image]

But I don't know how I can plot it like that in **matplotlib**. It would be great, if someone can help me with this.

Comment: what are the lengths of the confidence intervals? And what are their `x` coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `errorbar`:

```
def bland_altman_plot(data1, data2, *args, **kwargs):
    data1     = np.asarray(data1)
    data2     = np.asarray(data2)
    mean      = np.mean([data1, data2], axis=0)
    diff      = data1 - data2                   # Difference between data1 and data2
    md        = np.mean(diff)                   # Mean of the difference
    sd        = np.std(diff, axis=0)            # Standard deviation of the difference

    plt.scatter(mean, diff, *args, **kwargs)
    plt.axhline(md,           color='gray', linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(md + 1.96*sd, color='gray', linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(md - 1.96*sd, color='gray', linestyle='--')

    # set up params for ci_loa
    # change these accordingly
    ci_loa_height = np.std(mean)
    ci_loa_x = mean.min(), mean.max()

    # draw the errorbar/ci intervals
    # change color and capsize as wished
    plt.errorbar(ci_loa_x, [md + 1.96*sd]*2, 
                 yerr=ci_loa_height, fmt='none',
                 capsize=10, c='r')

    plt.errorbar(ci_loa_x, [md - 1.96*sd]*2, 
                 yerr=ci_loa_height, fmt='none',
                 capsize=10, c='r')
    plt.title('Bland-Altman Plot')
    plt.show()
```

Then:

```
np.random.seed(10)
bland_altman_plot(np.random.random(10), np.random.random(10))
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: That looks pretty good. I will have a look and then accept this answer. Thank you :)